# Google authentication Redirect_uri_missmatch error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, google-api, google-oauth, google-developers-console

I have checked all possible solution by other people and applied in my setting of app or in code but nothing is working for me.

Here is the parameter that I had passed to the baseUrl `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth`

- scope:`https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile`
- client_id:`xxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com`
- redirect_uri:`http://localhost:8228/Auth/ExternalLoginCallback?__provider__=Google&__sid__=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`
- state:`xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`
- response_type:`code`
- access_type:`online`

What i am missing? Please anyone suggest me something.

I got following error every time:

[image]

This is my App information:
[image]

**Update 1:**

Here is my code for `RequestAuthentication` method class for google:

```
public GoogleScopedClient(string cleintId, string clientSecretId)
        {
            this.cleintId = cleintId;
            this.clientSecretId = clientSecretId;
        }

        public string ProviderName
        {
            get { return "Google"; }
        }

        public void RequestAuthentication(System.Web.HttpContextBase context, Uri returnUrl)
        {
             string state = Regex.Match(returnUrl.AbsoluteUri, "(?<=__sid__=).*?($|&)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Value;

            string url = baseUrl + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(SCOPE.ToString()) +
                "&client_id=" + cleintId + "&redirect_uri=" +HttpUtility.UrlEncode(returnUrl.ToString()) 
+"&response_type=code&access_type=online";
  context.Response.Redirect(url);
        }
```

Comment: What do you get  in the Request Details?..By viewing this, I can guess you miss something on that.

Comment: Would you please submit your code so that we can see what you are doing.

Comment: @DaImTo please look into `Update 1`. I have added `RequestAuthentication` from my code.

Comment: Sorry that's not Google's official .Net code I have very little experience with the other Oauth library's so i am not going to be any help.  I suggest you hang out and wait for someone else to assist you.   Just remember Redirect URI you are sending must exactly match what you have entered in Google Developer console or the server will return the error you have now.   Check what you have in returnURL.

Comment: @DaImTo its okay thank you for the suggestion!! :)
Actually i have created a class named as 'GoogleScopedClient' of google under `RegisterClient`. So, i working like that for google api login.
 Yeah sure i will check the returnURL!!

Comment: This may help as well http://www.daimto.com/google-3-legged-oauth2-flow/   urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob would be your redirect URI

Answer (score 0):

Your redirect URI doesn't match. Specifically, what you've specified in Google Developer Console is `http://localhost:8228/Auth/ExternalLoginCallback/`, but what's being sent is `http://localhost:8228/Auth/ExternalLoginCallback` (without the trailing slash). Those are actually two entirely different URLs, even though, they usually go to the same place.

Comment: I have removed the `/` from my Google Developer Console but it shows me the same error.